# Error showing when i opening my xib file

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xib

iam using following code for opening xib when i click tableview row

```
ViewController *List=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:List animated:YES];
```

and iam getting this exception

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x245e052 0x1731d0a 0x2406a78 0x24069e9 0xbbe7d7 0xbbe9af 0xbbe6b7 0xabf36d 0x966e2c 0x9673a9 0x9675cb 0x967941 0x97947d 0x97966f 0x97993b 0x97a3df 0x97a986 0x97a5a4 0x41b08 0x93171d 0x931952 0x11b986d 0x2432966 0x2432407 0x23957c0 0x2394db4 0x2394ccb 0x391a879 0x391a93e 0x8a1a9b 0x28dd 0x2805)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Comment: What you have inside ViewController's viewDidLoad & viewWillAppear methods ?

Comment: default codes are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occuring because you are using Xcode 4.5+ (or previously the beta) which uses "auto layout" by default. Auto layout is only available on iOS 6 so you will get a runtime error on previous iOS versions.

You can fix this by opening your Storyboard, opening the Utilities pane, and disabling the "Use Autolayout" checkbox in the first tab/section:

[image]

For regular non-storyboard nibs, select the top-level view to access this option.

Comment: iam using xcode 4.6 .2 but the autolay ios there .now iam un checking it ,let me try

Answer (score 0):

You designed the view in IB using auto layout, but you are trying to run the code on an ios5 device or simulator?

EDIT: right, that class does not exist in iOS5! If you want this app to run in iOS5, you need to convert the xib from AutoLayout back to springs and struts. There is a checkbox in each XIB, in the right inspector view, to do this.